# How to map char values to int using enum

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to map some chars in a string to some integer values using enum. Please tell where am I going wrong?

```
enum moves{U,R,D,L};
class Solution {
public:
    bool judgeCircle(string moves) {   

// moves is a string having values like ULLDDRR, ULRD, UULLDDRR 
        int X[] = {0,1,0,-1};
        int Y[] = {1,0,-1,0};

// while iterating the string if I get a 'U' , I want to use it as an index 
//with  U representing the 0th index, R as index=1 and so on.. as specified 
 //in the enum

        int x=0 , y=0;
        enum moves ind;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < moves.length() ; i++ ) {
            ind = moves[i];  // but this line here gives error
            x += X[ind];
            y += Y[ind];
        }

        if(!x && !y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you post the full code?

Comment: Do not define `enum` if you want to use it as array. If you want to use as enum and still want to access as array here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321801/enum-c-get-by-index

Comment: What you are trying to do cannot be done, and is sort of weird enough that I can't recommend a better option because I don't know why you were trying to do it this way in the first place.

Comment: To map character values to `int`s use a `std::map<char,int> X = {{'u',0},{'r',1},{'d',0},{'l',-1}};` analogous for `Y`.

Comment: ...and also you have defined 'moves' twice. First as `enum` and then as `string`

Answer (score 2):

I would drop the idea with an `enum` because I feel it has no use for the actual problem – to map characters to navigation moves. For this, I would use a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). (Considering, that there are 4 entries only, the performance difference is probably hard to measure.)

While I was preparing a sample code, [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96) gave a similar hint. Though, I would even recommend to bundle x and y of moves together:

```
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// bundle x and y for a move (which needs both of them)
struct Move {
  int dx, dy;
};

// a type to map chars to moves
using MoveMap = std::map<char, Move>;

// a pre-defined move map
static const MoveMap mapMoves = {
    { 'U', { 0, 1 } },
    { 'R', { 1, 0 } },
    { 'D', { 0, -1 } },
    { 'L', { -1, 0 } }
};

/* a function to use move map
 *
 * id ... one of U R D L
 * x, y ... coordinates (update)
 * return: true if successful, (false e.g. for wrong id)
 */
bool move(char id, int &x, int &y)
{
  const MoveMap::const_iterator iter = mapMoves.find(id);
  return iter != mapMoves.end()
    ? x += iter->second.dx, y += iter->second.dy, true
    : false;
}

// check it out:

int main()
{
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  const char test[] = "ULLDDRR, ULRD, UULLDDRR";
  for (char id : test) {
    std::cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << "): "
      << "Move '" << id << "' -> ";
    if (move(id, x, y)) {
      std::cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n";
    } else std::cout << "failed\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(0, 0): Move 'U' -> (0, 1)
(0, 1): Move 'L' -> (-1, 1)
(-1, 1): Move 'L' -> (-2, 1)
(-2, 1): Move 'D' -> (-2, 0)
(-2, 0): Move 'D' -> (-2, -1)
(-2, -1): Move 'R' -> (-1, -1)
(-1, -1): Move 'R' -> (0, -1)
(0, -1): Move ',' -> failed
(0, -1): Move ' ' -> failed
(0, -1): Move 'U' -> (0, 0)
(0, 0): Move 'L' -> (-1, 0)
(-1, 0): Move 'R' -> (0, 0)
(0, 0): Move 'D' -> (0, -1)
(0, -1): Move ',' -> failed
(0, -1): Move ' ' -> failed
(0, -1): Move 'U' -> (0, 0)
(0, 0): Move 'U' -> (0, 1)
(0, 1): Move 'L' -> (-1, 1)
(-1, 1): Move 'L' -> (-2, 1)
(-2, 1): Move 'D' -> (-2, 0)
(-2, 0): Move 'D' -> (-2, -1)
(-2, -1): Move 'R' -> (-1, -1)
(-1, -1): Move 'R' -> (0, -1)
(0, -1): Move '' -> failed
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c804a4eec9c0b3d0)</kbd>

Comment: I had the same idea to combine `X/Y` moves into one pair, was just long for a comment :-)

Comment: Need C++11 though

Comment: @Atul I don't see why. This should work with c++-98 standards. (unless you mean the `using` statement, but that could be easily replaced with a `typedef`)

Comment: @Atul It should compile with C++11 as well. (At least it did with `g++ -std=c++11`.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Initializing `std::map` [compiles with and above C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138612/1911652) But anyways since OP has put tag C++11 I believe this should solve his/her problem.